# Dynamically change object in NHibernate

Tags: c#, nhibernate

I would like to use NHibernate to query a database with different objects. I have a string and depending on what that string is then I would like to return an object and query the db using that object. However, I am not sure what the best design of this would be.

Simple logic:

```
public object CheckString(string s){
    if(s == "A")
        return objA;
    else if(s == "B")
        return objB;
}

public void main(){
    var obj = CheckString("A");
    session.CreateCriteria<obj>().List<obj>();
}
```

Comment: `CreateCriteria<T>` requires a Type specification as the generic argument and not an object.

Comment: @stuartd so is there a way to create some sort of generic class that I can use to represent multiple types

Comment: [MakeGenericMethod](https://stackoverflow.com/a/232621/43846)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this overload `ICriteria CreateCriteria(string entityName)`:

```
public string CheckString(string s){
    if(s == "A")
        return "EntityA";//entity name from the database
    else if(s == "B")
        return "EntityB";//entity name from the database
}

public void main(){
    string entityName = CheckString("A");
    session.CreateCriteria(entityName).List<T>();
}
```